# How do I use the mouseenter and mouseleave events?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using `http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-0.9.5.js` and I'm not sure how to use the mouseenter and mouseleave events.  My code is below, and the click event works just fine.  How do I get the mouseenter and mouseleave events to work?

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

TestView = Ember.View.create
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile 'This is the view'
  click: (evt) ->
    console.log 'clicked'
  mouseenter: (evt) ->
    console.log 'mouse enter'
  mouseleave: (evt) ->
    console.log 'mouse leave'

TestView.append()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Events inside Ember.js are handled by `Ember.EventDispatcher` and the names are translated to a more Ember.js like convention if you will, see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/system/event_dispatcher.js#L48-73).

You have to change your mouse events to `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/QtZ2T/